# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'System.Runtime

Tags: c#

**Estoy haciendo una práctica en Visual Studio 2019 con conexión a una base de datos en SQL Server 2019, es un diseño de un formulario con usuario y contraseña, los datos de acceso son los que están almacenados en mi tabla de usuarios de mi base de datos Administrar, y el error me lo arroja cuando le doy iniciar: Anexo imagen del error y de mi diseño, asi como mis codigos espero y puedan ayudarme**

[image: IMAGEN DEL ERROR]

[image: DISEÑO]

**Adjunto el código de mi formulario:**

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 
using MiLibreria;
    
    namespace xDFactura {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                try
                {
                    string CMD = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Usuarios Where account='{0}' AND password='{1}'", txtAccount.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
                    DataSet ds = Utilerias.Ejecutar(CMD);
    
                    string cuenta = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["account"].ToString().Trim();
                    string contra = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString().Trim();
                    if (cuenta == txtAccount.Text.Trim() && contra == txtPassword.Text.Trim())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Se Inicio Correctamente");
                    }
    
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + error.Message);
                }
    
            }
    
            private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
        } }
```

**Adjunto el código de mi librería de clases:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MiLibreria
{
    public class Utilerias
    {
        public static DataSet Ejecutar(string cmd)
        {
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = Administrar; Integrated Security = True");
            Con.Open();

            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter DP = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, Con);
            DP.Fill(DS);
            Con.Close();
            return DS;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tu `dll` 'MiLibreria' esté compilada para un framework diferente del de tu proyecto?
Otra cosa, te recomiendo que añadas a las etiquetas de tu pregunta `c#`, ya que no tiene nada que ver con `sql-server`.
Saludos.